# Scala Future error handling with Either

Tags: scala, api, exception, error-handling

I am writing a wrapper for an API and I want to do error handling for applications problems. Each request returns a Future so in order to do this I see 2 options: using a `Future[Either]` or using exceptions to fail the future immediately.

Here is a snippet with both situations, `response` is a future with the return of the HTTP request:

```
  def handleRequestEither: Future[Either[String, String]] = {
    response.map {
      case "good_string" => Right("Success")
      case _ => Left("Failed")
    }
  }

  def handleRequest: Future[String] = {
    response.map {
      case "good_string" => "Success"
      case _ => throw new Exception("Failed")
    }
  }
```

And here is the snippet to get the result in both cases:

```
handleRequestEither.onComplete {
  case Success(res) =>
    res match {
      case Right(rightRes) => println(s"Success $res")
      case Left(leftRes) => println(s"Failure $res")
    }
  case Failure(ex) =>
    println(s"Failure $ex")
}

handleRequest.onComplete {
  case Success(res) => println(s"Success $res")
  case Failure(ex) => println(s"Failure $ex")
}
```

I don't like to use exceptions, but using `Future[Either]` makes it much more verbose to get the response afterwards, and if I want to map the result into another object it gets even more complicated. Is this the way to go, or are there better alternatives?

Comment: you may want to take look at this: https://gist.github.com/jnape/5299612

Answer (score 4):

Let me paraphrase Erik Meijer and consider the following table:

[image]

Consider then this two features of a language construct: **arity** (does it aggregate one or many items?) and **mode** (synchronous when blocking read operations until ready or asynchronous when not).

All of this imply that `Try` constructs and blocks manage the success or failure of the block generating the result synchronously. You'll control whether your resources provides the right answer without encountering problems (those described by exceptions).

On the other hand a `Future` is a kind of asynchronous `Try`. That means that it successfully completes when no problems (exceptions) has been found then notifying its subscribers. Hence, **I don't think you should have a future of `Either` in this case**, that is your second `handleRequest` implementation is the right way of using futures.

Finally, if what disturbs you is throwing an exception, you could follow the approach of `Promises`:

```
def handleRequest: Future[String] = {
   val p = Promise[String]
   response.map {
      case "good_string" => p.success("Success")
      case _ => p.failure(new Exception("Failed"))
    }
   p.future
}
```

Or:

```
case class Reason(msg: String) extends Exception

def handleRequest: Future[String] = {
   val p = Promise[String]
   response.map {
      case "good_string" => p.success("Success")
      case _ => p.failure(Reason("Invalid response"))
    }
   p.future
}
```

I'd rather use your second approach.

Comment: Thanks for the promise idea, I think I'll use that.

Comment: @nmat You're well come. I would say the second approach you proposed its cleaner. Composing a new future from other using map seems to me a much direct approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use special type for that: [EitherT](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.EitherT) from the [scalaz library](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz).

It works with scalaz enhanced version of `Either` : `\/`

It could transform combination of any monad and `\/` into a single monad. So using scalaz instances for `scala.concurent.Future` you could achieve the desired mix. And you could go further with monad transformers if you wish. [Read this beautiful blog if you're interested.](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+transformers.html)

Here not prettified but working with scalaz 7.1 example for you:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scalaz._
import scalaz.std.scalaFuture._
import EitherT._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object EitherFuture {
  type ETFS[X] = EitherT[Future, String, X]

  val IntResponse = "result (\\d+)".r

  def parse(response: Future[String]) =
    eitherT(response map {
      case IntResponse(num) ⇒ \/-(num.toInt)
      case _ ⇒ -\/("bad response")
    })

  def divideBy2(x: Validation[String, Int]) = 
    x.ensure("non divisible by 2")(_ % 2 == 0).map(_ / 2)

  def handleResponse(response: Future[String]) = for {
    num ← parse(response).validationed(divideBy2)
  } yield s"half is $num"

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Map(
      'good → "result 10",
      'proper → "result 11",
      'bad → "bad_string"
    ) foreach { case (key, str) ⇒
      val response = Future(str)
      val handled = handleResponse(response)
      val result = Await.result(handled.run, Duration.Inf)

      println(s"for $key response we have $result")
    }
  }
}
```